# IDA Decompiler generates wrong output on array of structures!

Tags: decompilation, hexrays, struct, array

There is a structure with size of 16-Bytes, and an array of it is defined.
The disassembly code for navigation through the array is:

```
MOV     i, i,LSL#4
LDR     R4, =arr_of_struct 
ADD     i, i, R4
LDR     var, [i]
```

But the decompiled code is:

```
var = arr_of_struct[4 * i];
```

Which is wrong and should be:

```
var = arr_of_struct[4 * i].field_0;
```

I think the problem is in first line of disassembly `MOV   i, i,LSL#4`. Obviously it is multiplying the array index by 16 which is the size of my struct. But IDA translated this line to `[4 * i]` !!!

So the first question is what's the reason of this behavior in IDA?
And the second is how can I fix this?

EDIT:
More information:

[image]

Comment: Which version of IDA and decompiler do you use?

Comment: IDA version 7.6 SP1, Decompiler ver 7.6.0.210427

Comment: You'll need to show more of the decompiler output. One line is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue, and post it here hope help someone someday...

I undefined the "arr_of_struct" (Ctrl+U), undefined both the array and also the structure variable:

[image: enter description here] **====>**  [image]

The output changed to deal with the undefined variable:

[image]

Declare struct variable again (Alt+Q), and define its location as an array (Pressing *), and the output changed to the right and expected shape:

[image]

Now I know how to fix it, but the first question is still remains:

**What's the reason of this behavior in IDA? Is there a sequence needed to consider while defining array of structures?**